# Why does the Xoom crash when sending a bitmap from one activity to another using intents?

Tags: android, bitmap, xoom

In my app, I take a screen shot of the current screen (using `view.getDrawingCache`) and send it to another activity as a bitmap using intents.

I have tested it on Galaxy Note 1, HTC one v, and Motorolla Xoom mz 604 tablet (10.1"). On the first two devices the code works fine. But on the Xoom tablet the code doesn't work: the tablet starts waiting for long time, and then app crashes.

What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: It might be because of "OOM".
What it is showing in logs ?
Try using getter setter methods or static bitmap.
Also sample your bitmap if it is big in size (Resolution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bitmap of a screenshot can get really big on a tablet, since the screen resolution is likely higher. The problem is probably a memory issue. To overcome this, you can write the bitmap to a temporary file and send the path to the file to the activity.

Alternatively, if the activity you're launching  is in the same application, you can use a global variable to hold the bitmap.

Comment: I have used a static variable which solves the problem.. Thanks for your help muhoweb

Answer (score 1):

I guest the problem its because of `OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget`

To get rid from this problem you can try to make one static variable then access in second activity rather than sending bitmap into intent.

**OR**

You can save the bitmap in internal memory and send path of that bitmap in second activity.

So get more in please post the logcat.